# Vigilant - part of speech?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Vigilant is an adjective, so "The vigilant worker spotted a problem" is correct but what about "We must remain vigilant"?

Comment: Adjectives can be predicates, after an auxiliary verb _be_, as in _She is vigilant, I told her to be more vigilant,_ and _We must remain vigilant_ (where the _be_ has been deleted after _remain_, which has a similar function).

Answer (score 1):

It’s still an adjective. That’s because *remain* is intransitive, like *be* or *become* or *seem*.  Here’s the relevant sense from the OED:

> 5. a. *intransitive*. With noun or adjectival phrase as complement: to continue to be.

In your example, the predicate complement is an adjectival phrase. Here’s one with a noun phrase as predicate complement:

> ‘I pass the test,’ she said. ‘I will diminish, and go into the West and remain Galadriel.’

She will remain Galadriel means she will continue to be Galadriel.